# Rails 5: Adding conditional custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to add a conditional  custom validation to a model

Rails allows to create methods in order to create custom validations

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if expiration_date.present? && expiration_date < Date.today
      errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")
  end
end
```

It also allows to create conditional validations

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  validates :card_number, presence: true, if: :paid_with_card?

  def paid_with_card?
    payment_type == "card"
  end
end
```

How can I mix both ?

My guess would be something like

```
validate :condition, if: :other_condition
```

But this creates a SyntaxError:

```
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you fix the missing closing `end` to opened `if` in `expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past`, you can have the following working:

```
validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past, if: :paid_with_card?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use each validator. For this you have to follow these steps:

- Create a folder named `validators` inside your `app` directory.
- Create a file named `some_validator.rb`
- Write codes as like:

  ```
  class SomeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
   def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
     return unless value.present?
     if some_condition1
       object.errors[attribute] << 'error msg for condition1'
     end
    object.errors[attribute] << 'error msg 2' if condition2
    object.errors[attribute] << 'error msg 3' if condition3
    object.errors[attribute] << 'error msg 4' if condition4
  end
  ```

  end
- Now validates by this custom validator, as like:
  `validates :attribute_name, some: true`
- Make sure your are giving the same name on validator. You can write the multiple conditions inside this custom validator.

Answer (score 2):

You missed end, corrected code:

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if expiration_date.present? && expiration_date < Date.today
      errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")
    end # this end you missed in code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :email_not_changeable, on: :update

  private

  def email_not_changeable
    return unless email_changed? && persisted?

    errors.add(:email, "can't be changed")
  end
end
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments or context about how this solves the original question.

Comment: Echoing @craigcaulfield; please add some comments around how this solves the original question.